# Accessing signatures of overriding methods in subclasses

Tags: python, inheritance, signature

In python3.8.5, I am working with an existing class `superCl`that defines a method `f`, and multiple existing subclasses `sub1`, `sub2`... that override `f` with different numbers of variables.  Based on [How to create new subclasses by adding the same method to multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54522022/how-to-create-new-subclasses-by-adding-the-same-method-to-multiple-classes/54522123), I would like to add a new function `g`to all subclasses via the superclass.  The new function should call `f`and do things with it.  The problem is that each subclass has a different signature for `f`.  How can I get around that?  Sample code follows:

```
import numpy as np

class superCl(object): # Exists already
    def f(self, x): return x

class sub1(superCl): # Exists already
    def f(self, x, a, b): return x / (b - a)
        
class sub2(superCl): # Exists already
    def f(self, x, tau): return 1/tau * np.exp(-x/tau)
        
sc = superCl()
print(sc.f(0))

s1 = sub1()
print(s1.f(0, 1, 2))

s2 = sub2()
print(s2.f(0, 1))

def g(self, x1, x2, ...): # New, calls existing method.  Is there some way to get the signatures and values from the subclasses, eg self.args?
    print('Extra meth')
    self.f(x1, ...) - self.f(x2, ...) # How to adapt to proper arguments for f for each sublcass?

superCl.g = g # New method gets added to new and existing instances

print(sc.g(0, 1))
print(s1.g(0, 1, 1, 2))
print(s2.g(0, 1, 1))
```

EDIT: Superclass defines a generic set of functions; subclasses are particular cases, each with different variables.  Function `f`returns value of function for subclasses parameters; function `g` I am trying to create evaluates the difference in `f` at two different points.

Comment: It’s difficult to suggest an answer without knowing what the parameters mean. For instance, you have ‘s2.f(2,3)’, so, if you call ‘s2.g()’, what parameters would you expect the subsequent call to ‘s2.f(...)’ have?

Comment: @quamrana Thanks for comment.  Have edited question.  ```f```is a function that depends on a variable ```x``` and on a subclass-dependent number of parameters.  Is there some way to access these with ```args```or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like using `*args` or `**kwds`does it ([Positional argument v.s. keyword argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450656/positional-argument-v-s-keyword-argument)):

```
import numpy as np

class superCl(object): # Exists already
    def f(self, x): return x

class sub1(superCl): # Exists already
    def f(self, x, a, b): return x / (b - a)
        
class sub2(superCl): # Exists already
    def f(self, x, tau): return 1/tau * np.exp(-x/tau)
        
sc = superCl()
print(sc.f(0))

s1 = sub1()
print(s1.f(0, 1, 2))

s2 = sub2()
print(s2.f(0, 1))

print('===========================================')
def g(self, x1, x2, *args): 
    print("args", *args)
    return self.f(x2, *args) - self.f(x1, *args)
superCl.g = g
print("--------------------\n"); print("sc", sc.f(1), '-', sc.f(0), "=", sc.g(0, 1))
print("--------------------\n"); print("s1", s1.f(1, 0, 4), '-', s1.f(0, 0, 4), "=", s1.g(0, 1, 0, 4))
print("--------------------\n"); print("s2", s2.f(1, 5), '-', s2.f(0, 5), "=", s2.g(0, 1, 5))

print('===========================================')
def h(self, x1, x2, **args): 
    print("args", args)
    return self.f(x2, **args) - self.f(x1, **args)
superCl.h = h
print("--------------------\n"); print("sc", sc.f(1), '-', sc.f(0), "=", sc.h(0, 1))
print("--------------------\n"); print("s1", s1.h(0, 1, a=0, b=4))
print("--------------------\n"); print("s2", s2.h(0, 1, tau=5))
```